# Python 3.9.1 trying to pull pip installs from /usr/local/lib/python3.8 Issue

Tags: python, pip

I currently am working with python. I've pip installed packages I need, but when I run my script, it is trying to pull my pip installed packages from /usr/local/lib/python3.8 while the packages are located /usr/local/lib/python3.9. Is there a way for me to repoint where the packages are being pulled from in my script execution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem. There are many ways to fix the issue. I assume your default pip/python is pointing to 3.8 version and hence the issue.

Having said that, the best practice for any python project is to create a virtual environment. Virtual Environment will allow your python distribution to be very specific to your project and does not use any of the the system libraries etc.

Its also best to distribute the project. This will also allow you to create multiple projects each running with different python distribution and have its own environment.

Here is the link you can use to install virtual environment.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Please note that the python version that will go to the virtual environment depends on the base version you will use to build the venv.

So to coming to your question, you can do this:

/usr/local/lib/python3.9 -m pip install xxxxxxx

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Could this issue be because I updated python? I'm working in a conda environment so I though that would help but it isn't. The conda environment says I'm using python 3.9.1, so every pip install goes to the python3.9/site-packages, but then executing python checks python3.8/site-packages and says they aren't there since they went to 3.9. I also tried your command but does not work for me.

Comment: Ok, I am assuming you are activating the conda environment and then trying to run pip. After activating the conda, can you send me the output of following commands please ?                                                                                                             
python --version

Comment: The output is 
Python 3.9.1

I did activate the new conda env with this. I'm assuming this is why the pip installs send it to /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages. I'm just not sure why running python scripts goes to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages to get packages instead

Comment: Ok lets try to resolve then. Can you share the output of following after activating conda env :  `which python`  and `head -10 your_python_script.py`  and `which pip`

Comment: which python : /usr/bin/python

head -10 my python script:
import os
import json
import geopandas
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely.geometry.multipolygon import MultiPolygon
from cartoframes.auth import set_default_credentials

which pip : /Users/usr1234/opt/anaconda3/envs/conda_env_test/bin/pip